In Virtual Box, I installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and then In Ubuntu some GUI apps Like Settings, Files, etc are not properly opening, loading and working
In Oracle Virtual Box (Latest Version meaning 7.0.20), I installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS using an .iso file, Ubuntu is working properly without any issues. But, when it come to GUI apps it's it note opening, working and not load correctly. Especially In case of File, Settings app. some other apps are not working too. Except Terminal, Desktop Interface and Snap Store mostly all app are not loading properly.
I go to the internet and the find some solutions and applied them, like reinstalling Files, Settings, boot repair, etc. but they don't work.



I allocated 128MB video memory (Additionally I enabled 3D acceleration), and I allocated 101GB disk space for the virtual machine. I Installed all required drivers and also installed VirtualBox Guest Additions.

I was able to solve this issue by disabling 3D Acceleration in VirtualBox. How to disable 3D Acceleration in VirtualBox
